# process.exit code tests for a function that is running form a script

Tags: ts-jest

I am running the converter function using a script and the process works correctly. But when I tried to write different tests for the functions nothing works and the log message is not describing many things.

converter function is basically a function that is run from the script using 4 args and I am trying to test that if the length is not 4 their process. exit should be called with 1.

```
import { writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import { convertTokens } from '../chakraToFigma';
7;
const readData = async (file: string) => {
  const data = await import('../../../' + file.slice('src/'.length));

  return data.tokens;
};

export const convert = async () => {
  const args = process.argv;

  if (args.length !== 4) {
    console.log(`usage: ${args[0]} ${args[1]} input output`);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  const data = await readData(args[2]);
  const output = convertTokens(data);
  writeFileSync(args[3], JSON.stringify(output), 'utf8');
};

convert();
```

my test is here :

```
import { convert } from '.';

describe('convert', () => {
  it('should set process.exitCode to 1 if arguments length is not 4', () => {
    const mockExit = jest.spyOn(process, 'exit')
      .mockImplementation((number) => { throw new Error('process.exit: ' + number) });

    expect(() => {
      process.argv = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]; 
      convert();
    }).toThrow();

    expect(mockExit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
    mockExit.mockRestore();
  });
});
```